# Notes and Attachments on Contacts in Customer Community

Tags: attachment, customer-community, notes

I don't see Notes and Attachments related list on Contacts.

From page 24  [Communities Implementation guide](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf)  it says Customer Users don't see Notes and Attachments related list on accounts or contacts

[image]

Also there is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrTdAAK)  related to customer portal

[image]

**Any work around for this ?**

Comment: Looks like you will have to roll your own notes and attachments objects